# Deploy Java executable in EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, nosql

I have written a little java tool to benchmark NoSQL databases. Because I dont have enough computers I want to run the benchmark tool and some database nodes in the Amazon EC2.

Is that possible?
-> Can I deploy a java app in the EC2 without any further config.?

Thank you

Comment: You should try it, it really depends on your app

Comment: thanks for your reply. What do you mean with it depends on your app.

Comment: What kind of do you need to do before running your application (settings, application server and so on). But generally it shouldn't be problem

Answer (score 2):

> Can I deploy a java app in the EC2 without any further config

Yes.  If you were running a typical web app, you might investigate Elastic BeanStalk. But that wouldn't work for benchmarking.

EC2 computers are just computers, except instead of installing the OS manually, you get to select a pre-installed OS to boot from, called an AMI. You could look around for an image with Java pre-installed, but it's fairly easy to boot your favorite [Ubuntu](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/)/Fedora/Centos/[AmazonLinux](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/) and do "apt-get install java" or "yum install java".

At first, you'll upload your program to the box and SSH in to test it. But when you get a workflow going, it's better to upload your program to S3, then have the box download it at boot. (S3 is usually faster than your upload speed, and more reliable.)

If you have just a "tiny" bit of config to do at boot, you can use [`cloud-init`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit). This will run a pre-defined script at boot. (Just put the commands in the EC2 user-data config at boot.) It could be as simple as 3 commands: install java, download my app, run my app.

For more sophisticated operations, you'll want to use [Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home), [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/), or [Ansible](http://www.ansibleworks.com/) to orchestrate multiple servers.

But for something simple like your benchmarking idea, you can easily "roll your own" using the AWS API. Use a library (Boto for Python, Fog for ruby. I'm sure there are several for Java) to write a program that does the following:
1) launch an instance with a cloud-init script that installs a NoSQL DB
2) wait for it to get an IP.
3) launch another instance with a cloud-init script that configures your java test program, and passes in the IP from step 2.
4) waits for it all to run, then collects the run info (or maybe the info is stored in S3 so you can collect it later)
5) cleans up by terminating the instances (It helps to tag them so you can clean up easier)

You could do all this manually, but when you find a bug, you'll want to re-run everything, and automation will make that a breeze. Plus, you'll want to repeat your findings on various instance sizes.

Once you get things working, you can switch to spot instances when running your actual benchmarks: They take longer to launch, but can save a ton of money. So spot instances are annoying for development, but perfect for running bulk tests where you don't care about the launch time.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of EC2 as just a set of computers that you can rent time on.   You have total control over the EC2 VMs, and can install and run almost any software you want on them, including database servers and your java app.

You'll probably find the practical limitation is the amount of time you want to spend setting them up.  You'll need to sign up for an Amazon account, set up your instances, install an OS, install DB servers, install your java app, etc...

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html to get going.